# Conditionally delete from two arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list

I want to delete the elements from an array, based off a condition of the elements in a second array.

For example

```
array1 = [1,2,3,4]
array2 = [5,4,3,2]
condition = 4
```

I want a loop that scans the second array, and if an index value is higher than the condition, it will delete that index from the 1st array. My attempt at pseudo code is:

```
for i in range(len(array2)):
    if array2[i] > condition:
        array1.pop(i)
```

Would result in

```
array1 = [2,3,4]
```

I think there is a more pythonic way of doing it with list comprehension. My arrays are ~4000 long and I'll be doing it a few times.

Thanks!

Comment: You want to delete elements from a list or create a new list? A comprehension is only suitable for the latter

Comment: Note, this approach will fail because you change the indices when you `pop` from the **list**. Try `condition = 3` and you will get `[2, 4]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A list comprehension would look like this:

```
[a for a, b in zip(array1, array2) if b <= condition]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `list-comprehension` with an if statement like so:

```
array1  = [x for i, x in enumerate(array1) if not array2[i] > condition]
```

Note that with all solutions utilizing lits-comprehensions you are not actually deleting or removing any items from `array1` but actually creating it again. What you are trying to do could be accomplished like so:

```
for j in sorted([i for i, n in enumerate(array2) if n > condition], reverse=True):
    array1.pop(j)
```

the `sorted` with `reverse=True` makes sure we will start `pop`ing items starting from the back of the array.